# How can I prevent memory interferences in a computer game

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management, game-development, steam

I am building an extension pack for a single player computer game, the extension pack will be purchased with steam's API and then I will have a representation of all the steamids of all the players with the items that they have purchased in my database.

Here's my concern: when a player logs in and sends a request to the server to get all the extension packs that they own and receives a response back, there needs to be some sort of a representation of the answer in the code, whether it is a boolean that represents access to a specific extension pack or a disabled button for items that they don't own. Can't players just edit that button/boolean using dll injection to gain access to that extension pack or even monitor the response from my server and change it? What would be the right way to do such a thing?

Comment: Sorry not to offer anything constructive but out of personal curiosity does Steam offer any support with this kind of thing?

Comment: @Absinthe You can use their API to open request for payments on the user's screen, and you can get events like successful payments and refunds. It is also possible to receive the player's steam_id. But as far as I know you should build your own solution as for storing the items and extension pack (unless they are steam's skins and are being sold in their marketplace. Which is not what I would like to do)

Comment: I meant more along the lines of customer service. Like with Unity - if you have a technical issue you can't solve you can get help from them.

Comment: Poll the clients occasionally and see what packs they have, verify that against what they're allowed to have, and then suspend/ban the accounts if they don't match.